# Elastica, KNP Paginator and Resultset > 10000

Tags: symfony, elastica, foselasticabundle, knppaginator

Pagination works fine even for large Results. It even shows that there are 25k Results for the Query. Pagination works fine for the first 10000 entries. Though, if i want to display entry 10000 - 10010 (for example) everything breaks with this Error:

`Uncaught PHP Exception Elastica\Exception\ResponseException: "Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [24240].`

I am using friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle. I've tried to set max_result_window with no luck, the Result window size does not change.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault, you have to reset the Index so that the changes to the max_result_window takes place!

I added this to the Elastica Configuration:

```
fos_elastica:
    indexes:
        app:
          settings:
            index:
              max_result_window: 50000
```

After changing the Configuration reset the Index, than populate it.